# Knockoutjs does not update viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my view I have file input:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" name="file_source" size="40"  onchange=''>
```

And span, in which I am showing the uploaded filename:

```
<span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info" data-bind="text: image"></span>

$(".file-input").change(function() {
           var elem = $("#upload-file-info");
           elem.html = $(this).val();
        });
```

This span is binded with knockoutjs:

```
viewModel = {
image: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The problem is that the observable do not updates when I update the span text. Althought I have the filename in the span, the observable is empty. How can I make the observable to update itself when the span text changes ?

Comment: How does `image` updates? In what way?

Comment: You are overwriting the `jQuery.fn.html` property of the element so this should do exactly nothing - it could work by using `elem.html($(this).val())` although I'm not sure whether KO supports two-way binding for <span> elements. I think you got the idea backwards, the common way to do this is that your `viewModel` controls your view. So you usually want to set the model and let the view be updated for you

Comment: On "file-input" change I append the file name in the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqrgth3u/) according to my comment on your question. This should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(".file-input").change(function () {
        var elem = $("#upload-file-info");
        viewModel.image($(this).val());
    });

    var viewModel = {
        image: ko.observable()
    };
    viewModel.image.subscribe(function (value) {
        alert(value);
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```